# Find all $\alpha$ such that $\frac{\cos \alpha - a \sin \alpha}{a \cos \alpha + \sin \alpha}$ is rational (given $a$ rational)

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers

Given $a$ rational, find **all** $\alpha$ such that the expression

$$\frac{\cos \alpha - a \sin \alpha}{a \cos \alpha + \sin \alpha}$$
is rational

Comment: What have you tried?  What progress have you made?

Comment: @saulspatz I only know that $a = \frac{1}{5}$ and $\alpha = \pi/4 rad $ works. It gives you $2/3$.

Comment: Doesn't $\alpha=\frac\pi4$ work for any rational $a\neq-1$?

Comment: @saulspatz The idea is to vary $\alpha$ and $a$ at the same time. If something is given, I prefer to set $a$, and then search $\alpha$.

Comment: So, you need to restate the question.  "Given rational $a$ find $\alpha$ such that ...".  Then one answer is $\alpha=\pi/4$ unless $a=-1$.

Comment: @saulspatz I edit the question from your comments. Preferable to find all answer.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{a^{-1} - \tan\alpha}{1 + a^{-1}\tan\alpha}=\tan(\alpha-\arctan a^{-1}).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\cos\alpha=0$ then the expression equals $-a$ and so is rational.  Suppose therefore, that $\cos\alpha\neq0$. On dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos\alpha$, the expression becomes $$\frac{1-a\tan\alpha}{a+\tan\alpha}\tag1$$ which is clearly  rational if $\tan\alpha$ is rational.

On the other hand, setting $(1)$ equal to $\frac pq$ and solving for $\tan\alpha$ gives a rational expression for $\tan\alpha$, so that we see that $(1)$ is rational if and only if $\tan\alpha$ is rational.

If you want values such that $\frac\alpha\pi$ is rational, then [Niven's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem)  says that this only occurs when $\tan\alpha\in\{-1,0,1\}$

Comment: divide by cos will not give your expression, it will give $\frac{1-atan(\alpha)}{a+tan(\alpha)}$

Comment: @LSS Yes, you're right.  It says that on my scratch paper, but I'm a terrible typist.  Thanks, I've corrected it.

Comment: If $\tan \alpha$ is rational then the expression is rational, But the other way implication is true?

Comment: @somenxavier If we set $(1)$ equal to a rational $r$ and clear denominators, we get a linear equation with rational coefficients for $\tan\alpha$, so the solution is rational.  Is there a problem I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\beta = arctan(a)$

Then the expression becomes

$$\frac{\cos \alpha - \tan \beta \sin \alpha}{\tan \beta \cos \alpha + \sin \alpha}$$

Divide both the numerator and denominator by $\cos \alpha$ to get

$$\frac{1 - \tan \beta \tan \alpha}{\tan \beta + \tan \alpha} = \frac{1}{\tan (\alpha + \beta)}$$

So we want to find all $\alpha$ such that $\tan (\alpha + \beta)$ is rational.

So the set of all $\alpha$ is given by $arctan(Q)-\beta+\pi k=arctan(Q)-arctan(a)+\pi k$ where Q is a rational number and k is an integer.